# Game Boy Player with Wii

Tags: nintendo-wii, nintendo-gamecube, game-boy, game-boy-player

I used to play GBA games at home with the [Game Boy Player](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Game_Boy_Player) accessory for the Nintendo Gamecube. It connects to the bottom of the GameCube, adding a base to it. Is there any way that it could be connected to the Nintendo Wii?

Comment: My advice:  Hold onto your GameCube.  It's still a great system.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, a Game Boy Player is not compatible with the Wii directly, as the Wii lacks the required Hi-Speed port availble on the Gamecube.

However, the Game Boy Player in combination with a Gamecube and a Seperate TV, is still a valid (but highly impractical) controller for the Gamecube and Wii games that support the GBA as controller.

Comment: Additionally, the Nintendo DS and DS Lite (not DSi, not DSiXL, not 3DS) are capable of playing GBA games.